# How can I compare a varchar in SQL Server ignoring tilde character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to compare a `varchar` column in SQL Server, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE varchar1 = 'variable'
```

but in the column there are values with the tilde character like `Tucumán`. So if you use

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE varchar1 = 'Tucuman'
```

there is no match. How can I get it to match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this option:

> COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AI

and that will do the trick.
In the example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE varchar1 = 'variable' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AI;
```